# I'm having a problem with sentences breaking when writing input and output in a latex algorithm

Tags: line-breaking, algorithms

In my algorithm, I wrote input and output as follows.

```
    \begin{algorithm}[htb!]
    \caption{Data Preprocessing}
    \label{alg:data_preprocessing}
    \textbf{Input} input data \\
    \textbf{Output} Preprocessed output dataset
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE
    ...
    \RETURN $processed\_output$
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

But I am facing a problem with the output as shown in the attached picture.

[image]

What is the cause of this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Answer (score 4):

You can leave a blank line between your **Input** and **Output** statements, which sets the proper alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Data Preprocessing}
  \textbf{Input} input data \\
  \textbf{Output} Preprocessed output dataset
    
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE Something
    \STATE \ldots
    \RETURN Something else
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

However, a better approach is to use the functionality provided by `algorithmic` through `\REQUIRE` (for input) and `\ENSURE` (for output):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Data Preprocessing}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE input date
    \ENSURE Preprocessed output dataset
    \STATE Something
    \STATE \ldots
    \RETURN Something else
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the formatting/style of the output produced by `\REQUIRE` and `\ENSURE` via a `\renewcommand` of their defaults:

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Ensure:}}
```